Schoenflies problem in PL setting
What is the status of the Schoenflies problem in the PL category? In other words, given an injective PL map $f:S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow S^n$, is it always PL equivalent to the equatorial inclusion? (I know the problem is still open for $n=4$.) Relatedly, is it true that a codimension one injective map of closed PL manifolds is always locally flat?  Also, relatedly, does topological locally flatness imply PL locally flatness in codimension one?

I believe that the case of $n = 3$ was settled by Alexander.  Perhaps you mean $n = 4$?

The problem is settled for all $n\ge 5$, mostly by the PL h-cobordism theorem.

@Moishe Kohan For applying the PL h-cobordism theorem one needs to prove first that $f(S^{n-1})$ divides $S^n$ into two topological $n$-discs. This could follow from the topological locally flatness of $f$ and the topological Schoenflies theorem. However, why $f$ is topologically locally flat? For example, given a non-trivial PL knot $f\colon S^3\hookrightarrow S^4$ (existence of such is an open problem), it is not completely obvious why its suspension $\Sigma f\colon \Sigma S^3\hookrightarrow \Sigma S^4$ is topologically locally flat.

I see what you are asking about: The PL formulation of Schoenflies that I am familiar with, assumes local flatness. Then the standard reference to a proof is the book by Rourke and Sanderson. Without the local flatness assumption, I do not think it is known.

The answer to this question for any $n\geq 4$ is positive iff it is positive for $n=4$. If there is a Schoenfiles PL embedding $f\colon S^3\hookrightarrow S^4$, which is not PL equivalent to the equatorial inclusion, then $\Sigma^{n-4}f\colon S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow S^n$ is not PL locally flat, $n\geq 5$, by induction looking at the map of links $S^{n-2}=L_a(S^{n-1})\hookrightarrow L_{\Sigma^{n-3}f(a)}(S^{n})=S^{n-1}$. (Note that it would still be topologically locally flat, since $f$ is trivial topologically.) Otherwise, any PL embedding $g\colon S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow S^n$ is PL locally flat and trivial by induction, see page 47 in "Introduction to piecewise-linear topology" by Rourke-Sanderson.

Do you have information about the codimension one case?

I am not sure I understand your question. The Schoenflies problem is the codimension one problem.

I was referring to the two "relatedly" questions.

The first two questions have a positive answer iff the answer is positive in the ambient dimension four. In other words, if any smooth or, equivalently, PL embedding $S^3 \to S^4$ bounds a standard disc (in dimension four any PL 4-manifold admits a unique smooth structure), then the answer is positive in all dimensions: any PL inclusion $S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow S^n$ is trivial for $n\geq 4$, any PL codimension one injective map  $M^{n-1}\hookrightarrow N^n$ is PL locally flat $n\geq 5$ (in ambient dimension 4 it is known to be true).

For the last question, I think any PL injective map $M^{n-1}\hookrightarrow N^n$ is topologically locally flat regardless it is PL locally flat or not. But in order to have an example of an injective PL map, which is not PL locally flat (but topologically locally flat) one needs a Schoenflies sphere $f\colon S^3\hookrightarrow S^4$ (a PL or smooth embedding which bounds an exotic disc).

The Schoendlies sphere itself is locally flat, but if one considers its (iterated) suspension $\Sigma^i S^3\hookrightarrow \Sigma^i S^4$, then it would be an example of a PL injective map which is not PL locally flat, but is topologically locally flat, because topologically any Schenflies sphere in dimension 4 is trivial.
